# Get image using JSONP C#

Tags: c#, json, jsonp

I want to get an image by passing a url using JSONP, what is the best way to go about this, can I do this without a library. What library should I use? any tutorials? thanks

Use a Callback Specify a callback URL via the callback=http://??? GET parameter. The URL will be called via a JSONP request and the location of the image passed, the receiving end can then integrate the image into the app. (the callback parameter should be urlencoded)

Answer (score 0):

for cross domain request I suggest this link:
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

try to pass the image path, it might work or with jsonp I think the other site should have web method that transforms the image into bytes and return it. You can search about Ajax upload download image to see how things can work for image.